# MySQL - ADD COLUMN raises errors on other columns

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a table where I store subscription data.

```
CREATE TABLE `subscription` (
  `StartTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `EndTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `UserID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Plan` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `StripeSubID` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StartTime`,`UserID`),
  KEY `Plan` (`Plan`),
  KEY `UserID` (`UserID`),
  CONSTRAINT `subscription_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Plan`) REFERENCES `plan` (`ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `subscription_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`UserID`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`Username`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would like to add a new column

```
ALTER TABLE subscription ADD COLUMN trial TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;
```

Point is that when I run the query, I get the error

> ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'EndTime'

I do not see the issue here, considering I'm adding a column while not touching the `EndTime` one. I looked for similar issues on the internet but found nothing.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I'm running MySQL version `5.7.32-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

Comment: My guess is tinyint needs a size,

Comment: @P.Salmon I tried `TINYINT(1)`, but the issue remains.